# Cequel:: InvalidSchemaMigration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cassandra, cql

I am new to Cequel and got this error `Cequel::InvalidSchemaMigration: Type changes are not allowed` on `rake cequel:migrate` for configuring Shape Log table.

My shape_log.rb file is:

```
class ShapeLog
   include Cequel::Record
   key :shape_id, :bigint
   key :id, :uuid, auto: true
   column :controller, :text
   column :action, :text
   map :change_set, :text, :text
   map :object, :text,:text
   column :remark, :text
   column :updated_by, :text
   timestamps
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with `rake cequel:reset` which drops keyspace if exists, then create and migrate. Hence, shape log table was configured.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful doing this. Check if you are connecting to the desired keyspace.

Since apparently there already exists such keyspace, you can run `rake cequel:keyspace:create`, which will fail because the keyspace already exists, and see what keyspace you are connecting to from the error message.